# Is it possible to display Event Custom Data when openning a pertaining Webform?

Tags: webform-civicrm, participants

When you open a Webform for an existing Contact, the Webform displays all the Contact info, including Contact Custom Data.

But, if the Webform contains Participant Custom Fields which had previously been filled, those are not populated, and you are blind for modifications.

Is there a way to have those Participant data displayed as well as Contact data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My notes suggest we added this feature about 7 months ago and you should be able to use pid1=xxx

Therefore using a url such as /node/92?pid1=15215 as a user who has permission to see the Contact involved should see the Contact and the Participation data load on the webform

If you have any problems doing so pls ping me and i will hunt down where our fix got to, but assume we pushed it back to core webform_civicrm

UPDATE

Scenario: Contact xx is registered to Event A and Event B.

Now, if "cid1=xx" is added to the URL - it loads all the participant information of the contact for Events included in the webform and fills the webform. So both event A and Event B will be chosen as selected. Lets say the participant id for event A is yy and the event B is zz.

With our changes(not yet submitted to core) - If a user adds "pid1=yy" to the URL, it will only load the event A information, giving the user the option to update their participant record values via the webform.

So a webform loaded with - "cid2=204&pid2=54" will update participant id 54 information attached to contact id 204.

This has not been pushed upstream (ie to core) as we would need to check if it doesn't harm any other components and create a PR if it seems to be a good addition.

Comment: Thank you Pete ; do you mean calling the webform this way : https://mysite.com/node/168?pid1=16 (where 16 is my Event id) ? Does not seam to work.

Comment: I'm guessing pid1 is a participant id?

Comment: yes davejenx is right P = Participant

Comment: Logical ! But it does not seem to work either in 5.6.0.. Two questions : 1/ how do I get de Participant Id to put it as an URL argument ? 2/ What about multi-participant Webforms (e.g. Parent + Children) ?

Comment: you may need the contactid as well. i don't have a quick answer for loading multiple existing participants on to a single form, but presumably you would need to build a View to get them all in to a single url which will depend on why certain participants should be grouped together (same payment?) but i can see this being possible (until proven otherwise)

Comment: edited above with new info

Comment: Thank you Pete : actually, it works on 5.6.0 with the following call : /node/168?cid1=xxxx&pid1=yyyy (contact_id and participant_id), but the form only populates the main participant of the webform.